# Error: object 'con' not found

Tags: sql, r, connection

I am trying to connect RStudio to MSSQL 2016 and I am getting the error message indicated in the subject line.  Code is below:

```
install.packages("RODBC")
library(RODBC)
con < - odbcConnect("AdventureWorksDW", uid="RUser", pwd="Swim1212**")
df_adventureworks <- as.data.frame(sqlQuery(con, "select * from 
vw_FactSales"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
close (con)
```

The error messages I get are:

> con < - odbcConnect("AdventureWorksDW", uid="RUser", pwd="Swim1212**")

**Error: object 'con' not found**

> df_adventureworks <- as.data.frame(sqlQuery(con, "select * from vw_FactSales"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

**Error in inherits(channel, "RODBC") : object 'con' not found**

> close (con)

**Error in close(con) : object 'con' not found**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your object assignment. A space between the "<" and the "-", hence the "not found error":

```
con < - odbcConnect("AdventureWorksDW", uid="RUser", pwd="Swim1212**")
```

Try with this instead:

```
con <- odbcConnect("AdventureWorksDW", uid="RUser", pwd="Swim1212**")
```